# Docker Compose optional extra_hosts entry from ENV variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My goal is to conditionally include an entry in `extra_hosts` in my docker compose file.

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
    my_service:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        extra_hosts:
            - "example.com:10.1.1.1"
            - ${MY_OPTIONAL_HOSTNAME}
```

When the ENV var `MY_OPTIONAL_HOSTNAME` is set, it works as expected, but when it's not set, I get the error below:

```
$ docker compose up
time="2024-02-19T18:56:12+10:00" level=warning msg="The \"MY_OPTIONAL_HOSTNAME\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'services[my_service].extra_hosts': bad host name ''
```

What is a "valid empty value" to set `MY_OPTIONAL_HOSTNAME` to, or how can I ignore it when not set?

Comment: Maybe: `${MY_OPTIONAL_HOSTNAME:-"host.docker.internal:host-gateway"}`

Comment: I was indeed looking for something like that to set as the default value, thanks for sharing. Let's see if someone else has a different approach, otherwise I think I'll have to go with this solution.

Comment: I tried it here, apparently the correct syntax is: `${MY_OPTIONAL_HOSTNAME:-host.docker.internal:host-gateway}`

Comment: great! Sometimes quotes are a mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to use interpolation with a default value

```
services:
my_service:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    extra_hosts:
        - "example.com:10.1.1.1"
        - ${MY_OPTIONAL_HOSTNAME:-host.docker.internal:host-gateway}
```

More info: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/env-file/#interpolation